# "Thought of" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

I am designing a solution within the context of a certain domain/area. The solution could suit other domains/areas as well.

I want to say that my solution is designed and implemented to solve problems related to a specific domain and not others.

Can I say: "my solution is mostly thought of in the context of something "

Comment: "my solution is mostly thought of in the context of something" is a lot of words to say nothing of consequence.

Comment: How about, "my solution applies (specifically) to domain x"? Or "is intended for"? If you want to be vaguer, you could say, "devised/created with x in mind". I would rather you "thought of" in expressions like, "x can be thought of *as* (a type of) y".

Comment: It does make sense, but it's a little wordy.  Perhaps "My solution is mostly within the scope of [something]".  "My solution mostly relates to [something]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I say: "my solution is mostly thought of in the context of something."

No. It does not convey your meaning of

> *"my solution is designed and implemented to solve problems related to a specific domain and not others."*

That statement is quite clear: It is exclusive.

The problems with *"my solution is mostly thought of in the context of something"* are

1. "mostly" = this is not exclusive. There will be other domains in which it is applicable.
2. The main use of "thought of" is in the construction "thought of (as something)" = associated with (something.)

For example: *Honey is *mainly thought of as* something to eat, but did you know that it is also an excellent antibiotic?"*

3. If you are designing a solution, it will be new. It therefore will be false to say that it is "thought of" - nobody can think of it because nobody has heard of it.

Once your solution is popular and being implemented by many, it is still wrong as it is not "thought of" it is "used".

This use of "thought of", in this context, is ambiguous and cannot be relied on to carry the meaning of *"people realise it is the solution"*: it means that your solution suddenly enters their mind when they see that something.

Answer (score 1):

No. Idiomatic is

- *This solution is/was designed primarily with applications in the field of [specific domain] in mind.*

> **with something in mind** [phrase]
>
> If you do something with a particular thing [or person] in mind, you do it with
> that thing as your aim or as the reason or basis for your action [or
> as the intended field of application, person to be impacted ...]

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/with-something-in-mind)] [augmented]

Comment: Hi! I upvoted your answer!